# Nav wont align to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help my .nav wont text-align: right; properly

[image]

```
<div class="logo">
<h2><i class="icon-reorder"></i> Frosty</h2>
</div>
<div class="nav">
<a href="#">Home</a>
</div>

div.logo, div.nav { display: inline-block; }
div.nav a { text-align: right; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `float: right` instead of `text-align: right`.

You can also move it to the right putting a `position: relative` to the container above (in your case `main-container`) and putting `position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px` in `nav` class.

Comment: I want them to be like lined up perfectly the nav is above the h2

Comment: Try to use `vertical-align: bottom`

Comment: No luck :( any other ideas?

Comment: Can you put a little more of your html?

Comment: Updated the answer. I think that in your case `right: 45px; bottom: 35px` is good values to align your text.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are setting only the anchor tag to `text-align: right`. If you want the whole nav to be sent to the right, you're gonna want to apply CSS to `div.nav` and not `div.nav a`.

You need to set a width if you want to use `text-align: right` but I would recommend using `float: right` but it depends on you. Floating will literally make your elements "float" so items can appear under it. For more information on float, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

remove text-align from div.nav a

and add this to div.nav

```
text-align:right;
```

perhaps A tag wraps around text and cant align it altho the parent di in this case nav is 100% width